# NHibernate QuerySyntaxException

Tags: nhibernate, exception

I am following along with the [Summer of NHibernate Screencast Series](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) and am running into a strange NHibernate Exception.

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException:
Exception of type
'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown.
[select from DataTransfer.Person p where p.FirstName=:fn].
```

I have deviated from the Screencast Series in the following ways:

1. Running against an MS SQL Server Compact Database
2. I am using MSTest instead of MbUnit

I've tried any number of combination of queries always with the same result. My present CreateQuery syntax

```
public IList<Person> GetPersonsByFirstName(string firstName)
{
    ISession session = GetSession();

    return session.CreateQuery("select from Person p " +
        "where p.FirstName=:fn").SetString("fn", firstName)
        .List<Person>();
}
```

While not a direct query this method works

```
public Person GetPersonById(int personId)
{
    ISession session = GetSession();
    return session.Get<Person>(personId);
}
```

My *hibernate.cfg.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory name="BookDb">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=C:\Code\BookCollection\DataAccessLayer\BookCollectionDb.sdf</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <mapping assembly="DataTransfer"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

*Person.hbm.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="DataTransfer" namespace="DataTransfer">
  <class name="DataTransfer.Person,DataTransfer" table="Person">
    <id name="PersonId" column="PersonId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName" type="String" length="50" not-null="false" />
    <property name="LastName" column="LastName" type="String" length="50" not-null="false" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was also following the [Summer of NHibernate Screencast Series](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) and came across the same problem.

The problem is in the HQL "**select from User p**" change that to "**select p from User p**" or just "**from User p**".

> The ’shorthand’ HQL form that was used in the screencasts under NHibernate version 1.2 was **deprecated** in 2.0 and **eliminated** in 2.1.x as the default query parser was switched out to be the more strict option.

```
public IList<Person> GetPersonsByFirstName(string firstName)
{
    ISession session = GetSession();

    return session.CreateQuery("select p from Person p where p.FirstName=:fn")
                              .SetString("fn", firstName)
                              .List<Person>();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you're specifying the namespace in the `<hibernate-mapping` element, you could write :

```
 <class name="Person" table="Person">
  ....
```

After you try that, if it doesn't work - I have no idea why it isn't working. I've tried pretty much the example you gave and it worked .

I have seen the new parser throw some weird errors and you just have to go by trial and error when it happens :(.

**Edit**

About the trial and error : you could change the query to "from Person" see if that works(if it doesn't...i'm stuck ) . Then add the filter, first try directly p.FirstName = 'x'. Then try with parameter. You could try not adding the alias.

Also, try using the latest version of NH.

**Edit 2**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateTests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" namespace="NHibernateTests">

<class name="User" table="`User`" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<id name="Id" type="Int32" column="UserId">
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
<property name="UserName" type="String">
  <column name="UserName" not-null="true" />
</property>
<property name="FName" type="String">
  <column name="FName" />
</property>
  </class></hibernate-mapping>
```

and the query :

```
IList<User> users = session.CreateQuery("select from User p " +
                              "where p.UserName=:fn").SetString("fn", "u")
                  .List<User>();
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: Made the change to *Person.hbm.xml* to no avail. You indicate that trial and error is a way to work through weird NHibernate parser errors, what sort of trials should I be doing?

Comment: Changed select to simply "select from DataTransfer.Person p" and received same error. I am using Build 2.1.0 of NHibernate. Are you using a MS SQL Server Compact Database? The only other difference I can see between our work is that you are being more explicit about the NHibernateTests assembly in *User.hbm.xml*. Other thoughts?

Comment: did you try leaving the select just : "from Person"(it's legitimate in hql) ? I'm actually testing against sqlite but I doubt it matters as the antlr parser works towards generating the query and if the database was the problem you would get an sqlexception

Comment: and no, the explicit assembly is not causing this.

Comment: didn't realize you meant just "from person p". That totally worked, what's the deal? Figured it wasn't the assembly but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: wait, so it works with the filter too ? WOHOO :). Not sure what the problem was, again, you can see the query I tested and worked ... so, not sure. You could also ask on the nhusers group on google. They might have more detail.